# map dynamic array in react from a smart contract with values an address and a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, solidity

I am trying to map a dynamic array with an address and a string from solidity to react to look like a table or print out the address and string in a list but I can't manage to separate those 2 values.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Data: []
    };
  }

  GetData = async () => {
    const { accounts, contract, count, Data } = this.state;
    const data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
      const dataa = await contract.methods.getInfo(i).call();
      data.push(dataa);
    }
    console.log(data);
    this.setState({ Data: JSON.stringify(data) });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <button onClick={this.GetData}>Show</button>
        <h1>{this.state.Data}</h1>
      </>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

This is what my console prints and it shows the data in the website as `0:<address> 1: <string>`

```
(2) [Result, Result]
0: Result
0: "0x7e3ce0fc8F95Bb83A4f5131912DacBFf11B9d4f8"
1: "{test1}"
__proto__: Object
1: Result {0: "0x514bdB4F417926027dDa4f0ccb2a6674a31D4BcB", 1: "{test2"}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try separating before you `stringify`. Actually, why do you stringify at all?

This should do:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Data: []
    };
  }

  GetData = async () => {
    const { accounts, contract, count, Data } = this.state;
    const data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
      const dataa = await contract.methods.getInfo(i).call();
      data.push(dataa);
    }
    console.log(data);
    this.setState({ Data: data });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <button onClick={this.GetData}>Show</button>
         { this.state.Data.map(item => <h1>{item.toString()}</h1>) }

      </>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: it prints [object Object] now

Comment: it worked now by adding the entries to a separate array and mapping those instead! Thank you